# Defining a curve that N% of data are under itself in Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, prediction, confidence-interval

I have a data set and a parabolic adjustment curve. Now I need a parabolic curve that contains 95% of my data below it and another curve that contains 5% of it. From what I have tested, it is not about confidence or prediction bands, but something else I don't know. The image below illustrates approximately what I need. can anybody help me? It can be with Excel or Matlab. [Here is my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIWLn.png)

Comment: Are there not an infinite number of possible curves that satisfy each criterion? I'm sure there's a much cleverer way, but I might start by fitting the data with a generic curve and then brute-forcing it using gradient descent until you arrive at the correct values.

Comment: @Scott How can I use this gradient descent?

Comment: I guess I used the term nontechnically, but suppose you fit the data with a function f(x) that bisects the data. Adjust the value of the parameter X in small increments. If you're aiming for a curve that sits above 95% of the data make note of whether each change in X gets you closer or further from this goal. If it gets you closer keep moving X in that direction. If it gets you further, change the direction... same thing can be done with 2+ input parameters but then you have to descend along a multidimensional surface which is much more computationally intensive